# Is there a way to specify a sort for a query in Report Builder 3.0, not using Edit as Text?

Tags: reportbuilder

In Report Builder 3.0, you can open a report, or a query.  When you open up a query, you're in a full-screen visual query designer.

I cannot figure out how to indicate that I want to sort columns in this designer.  There is an "Edit as Text" mode.  When I go in there, it shows the SQL statement.  I can add an ORDER BY clause at the end, and when I run the query, this works fine.

However, once you edit a query in "Edit as Text" mode, you cannot switch back to the visual designer.  When you try, it tells you that you'll lose the changes you made to a changed query, or the whole SQL statement to a saved "Edit as Text" query.  And sure enough, you do!

Did I miss something, or is there really no way to indicate a sort for a query in the Report Builder 3.0 visual designer?

Comment: This has astounded me as well.

Comment: I can't find the answer either.  It seems almost unbelievable that you can't do this.  In their desire to make the Query Designer unintimidating, Microsoft seem to have taken out quite a bit of the functionality (I can't find a way to see the number of rows returned either).

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to do this in the Query Designer either.  However, once you you attach a dataset to a table object in the report, you can open up the table properties and specify the sort order on it.  For example, insert a table and associate your dataset with the table.  In the design view of the report, right click on your newly created Tablix object.  Click on "Sorting" in the left pane and add the fields on which you wish to sort.